# How can I set the power on default state of serial port on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, serial-port

How can I set the DTR line to high by default when a Windows 7 machine starts up?

Background:  My own Windows service sets the condition of the com port lines to indicate its status.  One of these is DTR high when in a startup state.  However, since my service is set to delayed start, there is a period (2 mins, I think) when the DSR line is low after the machine is powered up, before my service starts and sets the DTR line to high.

Answer (score 0):

You choices are:

1. Write code as a Device driver tagged BOOT_START which will load early but file system and other services would not necessarily be available.
2. Tweak the order that your service starts see ServiceGroupOrder value in 
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control` and if you are booting from an SSD then your time will be reduced significantly.

Comment: 3. Pull up the external side of the DTR signal when the computer is switched on, and disconnect the pull-up resistor when the program is ready. Implementation details may be a little more involved.